# Como adicionar muitos clientes de uma só vez em uma tabela de banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Preciso adicionar Nome, Telefone e Endereço de muitos clientes que estão no excel e passar isso para o banco de dados. Qual seria a forma mais rápida de fazer isso ?

Comment: Gerar um csv e mandar importar via linha de comando.

Answer (score 0):

Exportando para CSV você pode usar o HeidiSQL para importar como nesta dúvida respondida (em inglês)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table

ou usar o comando LOAD DATA do MySQL descrito na documentação (em inglês) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Apenas tome cuidado com um detalhe: devido a numeração o Excel exporta CSV não sepradao por vírgula, mas por ponto e vírgula.